# Sending gmail using gmail api javascript

Tags: javascript

I need some help here:

When I use debugger, everything works, but when debugger is not used, it not working.

When `getAjax` function is not called to get data from local server, then it the program is working and it can send mail

```
function sendMessage(headers_obj, message, callback) {
  var pGmail = $('#compose-to').val();
  getAjax(pGmail).then(result => {
  var email = '';
  message = encryptText(result, message);
  for (var header in headers_obj) {
    email += header += ": " + headers_obj[header] + "\r\n";
  }
  email += "\r\n" + message;
  alert(email);
  if(email!=null|| email!=''){
    var mail = encodeBase64(email);
    var sendRequest = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.send({
      'userId': 'me',
      'resource': {
         'raw': mail
       }
    })
    sendRequest.execute(callback)
  } 
})
}
 function getAjax(pGmail) {
   return new Promise((resolve) => {
    $.ajax({
     url: 'http://localhost:7777/' +
     '?pmail=' + pGmail + '&method=where', success: function (result) {
      return resolve(result);
    }
  })
 });
}
```

Comment: sounds like a CORS issue on your server

Answer (score 1):

Trick lies in the time delay.

> When I use debugger, everything works, but when debugger is not used, it not working

When you are in Debug mode, the `getAjax` call is able to complete its request and the response is arrived. Since while debugging there is a small time delay for us to step over to next line of code.

> When getAjax function is not called to get data from local server, then it the program is working and it can send mail

Obviously there is no need to of time delay here, since you are not calling `getAjax` function.

**Few Solution Approaches**

Option 1 : Make it synchronous

Even though the getAjax is an asynchronous call, we can wire up the email sending code in the response of getAjax call, thus making it synchronous,

Option 2 : Introduce a time delay between `getAjax` and email sending code.

Please note in this approach, the time delay which might be higher or lower than the time taken by getAjax function and in some cases it may fail, if the getAjax call doesn't respond within in the time delay.

Choose the option which suits best for your scenario.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I try option 1 before, but it still like that. I use function getAjax to get data from my server and send by mail. I try to use async-await and the same thing happen

Comment: getAjax(pGmail).then((pKey)=>{
        var result = encryptText(pKey, message);
        if(result!=null || result!=''){
           sendEmail(result);
          }   
      })

Comment: i do like this, but i think my local server has proplem

Answer (score 0):

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
     user: "root",
    password: "1234",
    database: 'publickeyserver'
 });  

 con.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
   });
 http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var query = url.parse(req.url, true).query;


     switch (query.method) {
       case "insert":
           var pkey = new Buffer(query.publickey, 
          'base64').toString('ascii');
          insertKey(query.pmail, pkey, res);
          break;
        case "where":
           getKey(query.pmail, res);
            break;
         default:
          console.log("Error");
       }
   }).listen(7777);
 function insertKey(pmail, publickey, res) {
   var value = [[pmail, publickey]];
   var sql = "INSERT INTO publickey (GmailId, PublicKey) VALUES ?";
  con.query(sql, [value], function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("success");
      res.write('success');
      res.end();
  });
}
 function getKey(pmail, res) {
   console.log(pmail);
    var sql = 'SELECT PublicKey FROM publickey WHERE GmailId = ?';
    con.query(sql, [pmail], function (err, result) {
       if (err) throw err;
        res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/plain" });
        res.end(result[0]['PublicKey']);
        console.log(result[0]['PublicKey']);
     });
  }
```

Here is my server code, i use nodejs